# How to get every word out of a string?

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a problem where I need to get every word in the sentence and sort it alphabetically. I would really appreciate some help in the matter, as I don't quite have a clue about how to get every word separately inside a list so i could sort it. Thanks for your time!
I have tried using a for loop to search for every space but it didn't seem to work out as I didn't have quite enough of an idea how to get the word itself out.

```
    if action = "sort"
        for word in text:
            if word == " ":
                pass
```

Comment: *Hint*: `split` and `sort`.

Comment: Use `split()`: `words = text.split(' ')`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the split method like so.

```
s = "your string"
lst = s.split() # would return lst = ["your", "string"]. split could take a separator parameter. s.split(“r”) -> ["you", " st", "ing"]

lst.sort() # this would sort your words
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 steps to take:

1. Convert the string into a **list** of words
2. **Sort** the list from the previous step

Code

```
sentence = 'split this sentence'
words_list = sentence.split(' ')
sorted_word_list = sorted(words_list)
```